# How to change font style in Mediaroom PF application?

Tags: mediaroom

In mediaroom PF application how can we change the font. in below code

```
<mrml:TVLabel ID="value1" runat="server" **FontStyle="reg16"** 
            Foreground="argb(255,235,235,235)" Padding="rect(10,0,0,0)" 
            style="position: absolute; top: 45px; left: 0px; height: 88px; width: 250px;" 
            Text="-" >
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `mediaroom` but I suppose that writing the required `CSS` style into the `style` attribute will work for you. If you are new to `CSS` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. All you can do is use the predefined fonts available already on the STB/Simulator. The full list is in the files Styles.xml and Skin.xml.

You can find the definition like this:

```
  <!-- FONTs in the system -->
  <constant name="TVReg" value="fonts/SegoeAltMRSB.ttf"/>
  <constant name="TVBold" value="fonts/SegoeAltMRB.ttf"/>
  <constant name="TVItalic" value="fonts/SegoeAltMRSBI.ttf"/>
  <constant name="TVBoldItalic" value="fonts/SegoeAltMRBI.ttf"/>
  <constant name="TVHeader" value="fonts/SegoeAltMRB.ttf"/>
```

And them a lot of styles like that:

```
<font styleName="Bold16" fontFace="@TVBold" fontSize="16"/>
```